# Android: conversion from millisecond to min-sec format returns a wrong value

Tags: android

This is a short snippet that converts the millisecond value to the String-formatted min-sec format.

```
private String fromMillisecToFormattedTime(long millisec) {
    return String.format("%d:%d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisec),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisec),
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisec))
    );
}
```

I wrote this code to get the running time of media, but the value shown from this method does not return what I expect. For example, the original running time of a sample media is 4:12, while the method returns 4:252.

Any solutions to correct the calculation?

Comment: yes: use `android.text.format.DateUtils#formatElapsedTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to substract the values and not append it, 
try this:

```
return String.format("%d:%d",
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisec),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisec)- TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisec))
);
```